# After payment my php site gets logged out, not comes to the payment success page

Tags: php, payment-gateway, gateway

I am building a php website (https://demosite.tripura.gov.in/) where logged in users can do payment for some service. Now what happens is that, payment happens successfully (debit from bank) and as expected after payment user is redirected to a payment success page (pay_response.php) but **SOMETIMES** it doesn't, it automatically logged out and goes to site homepage.
The fun fact is, from localhost site it always works, **but from production it sometimes works sometimes not**.

Any suggestion to change the flow / or to update code ?

**This is my payment page (payment.php)-**

```
 <?php
session_start();
// check session
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_mobile"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
// headers
header("X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN");
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
header("X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block");
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"); 
header("Referrer-Policy: same-origin");
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php 
$merchant_id = "xxxx";
$security_id = "xxxx";
$checksum_key = "xxxx";
$customer_id = round(microtime(true) * 10000);
$amount = 10.00;
$additionaltxt1 = xxxx;       
$user_uid = xxxx;                                        
$return_url = 'https://demosite.tripura.gov.in/pay_response.php';  
                                      
$str = $merchant_id . '|' . $customer_id . '|NA|'.$amount.'|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|R|'.$security_id . 
'|NA|NA|F|' . $additionaltxt1 . '|'.$user_uid.'|NA|NA|NA|NA|NA|'.$return_url;

$checksum = strtoupper(hash_hmac("sha256", $str, $checksum_key, false));
$payment_string = $str . '|' . $checksum;
 ?>

 <form method="POST" action="https://pgi.billdesk.com/pgidsk/PGIMerchantPayment">
 <input type="hidden" name="msg" value="<?php echo $payment_string; ?>">
 <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value='PAY'>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**My payment success page (pay_response.php)-**

```
<?php
session_start();
// check session
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_mobile"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$resp_str = $_POST['msg']; // msg holds the payment response sent from gateway
$resp_arr = preg_split("/\|/", $_POST['msg']);
$response_code = $resp_arr['14'];
echo $response_code;
// storing payment response to database
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"This is my payment page (payment.php)"_ - don't see any `session_start` in there?

Comment: _"My payment success page (pay_response.php)"_ - setting session parameters in one specific location only, is not a good idea. Your session file might for example get garbage collected earlier, when _another_ script uses a lower timeout. And why are you trying to set a cookie with the session name in there yourself? (Instead of letting session_start handle it.)

Comment: @CBroe just missed while asking question, it is there in my page. Now ?

Comment: Checking the `SameSite` flag value of your session cookie might be a good start.

Comment: @CBroe talking about the headers right ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value

Comment: try to send the return_url after urlencoding and let me know if it redirects or not